# Interpreting regression coefficient for model with log(y+1) transformed outcome variable with small y

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, causality

I have a model which is aiming to estimate the ATE (average treatment effect) of a binary treatment on a count data outcome variable. Since the outcome can sometimes take a 0 value, I use the transform log(y + 1) to cope with this.

With log transformed outcome variables, you can interpret your ATE result as a percentage. However, I'm unsure how to reason about the marginal effects for my log(y+1) case given the treatment impact as a percentage fluctuates, especially at low levels of y. The below is as far as I've got with this.

We can use $ \hat{ATE} $ to relate hypothetical outcomes without ($ y_1 $) and with ($ y_2 $) treatment using the following...

$ log(y_2 + 1) - log(y_1 + 1) = \hat{ATE} $

$ \frac{y_2 + 1}{y_1 + 1} = exp(\hat{ATE}) $

$ y_2 = exp(\hat{ATE})(y_1 + 1) - 1 $

$ \frac{y_2}{y_1} = exp(\hat{ATE}) + \frac{exp(\hat{ATE}) - 1}{y_1} $

We can convert the $ y_2/y_1 $ ratio to a percentage $ (\hat{ATE}_{pct}) $ as below...

$ \hat{ATE}_{pct} = (exp(\hat{ATE}) + \frac{exp(\hat{ATE}) - 1}{y_1} - 1) * 100 $

Given the median untransformed outcome in my dataset is 10, the differences in percentage impact of treatment are non-trivial for different levels of y.

How would you recommend interpreting this so others can better understand my results?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks